# Sanitizing database inputs in Matlab?

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

Does Matlab's database toolbox have a function to sanitize inputs?  I can't find any mention of one in the documentation.

I have a bunch of strings that I'd like to write to a MySQL database. Some of the strings contain apostrophes, and these are causing errors.  I'm looking for a simple way to preprocess the strings to make them database-friendly.

Also, it's not necessary in my application to be able to reconstruct the original strings exactly. The preprocessing step never needs to be "undone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used matlab's [genvarname](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/genvarname.html) function to preprocess my strings. This function doesn't do database sanitization, per se, and it's not invertible, but it does remove apostrophes. It met my needs.